# How can I have links which do different things in Backbone.js without using eval()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have links which I want to do different things depending on the link. Therefore I have a datastructure:

```
var data = [{"name":"foo", "onClick":"baz()"}, {"name":"bar", "onClick":"bam()"}];
```

Currently, in the view i have a function run which takes the item and does eval(item.onClick), and that works, just it feels like a security hole.
I could put the onClick into the html when rendering the view, but that feels wrong.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can embed function in the data

```
var data = [{"name":"foo", "onClick":baz}, {"name":"bar", "onClick":bam}];
item.onClick();
```

You can look [here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx) for more helpful stuff how to do it

Comment: This probably do not change the possible security question but it does work. But as long as you can trust the source, there is no security risk with either, just do not eval anything users might enter.

Answer (score 3):

Backbone views have a [delegateEvents function](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-delegateEvents):

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

  events: {
    "click button[name='foo']": "baz",
    "click button[name='bar']": "bam"
  },


  baz: function(){ ... }

  bam: function(){ ... }
```

Comment: the problem with this is that it doesnt allow the method to be data driven

Answer (score 0):

Easy -- even if you don't implement an object container for your function call.

```
function baz(){ 
    ....
}
function bam(){ 
    ....
}
```

And, assuming you have this as your JSON callback:

```
function jsonCallback(data){
    /*some code*/
    window[data.onClick]();
    /* some more code */
}
```